# Best place to retrieve crucial data first time from server, before any other app component starts

Tags: android, android-lifecycle

The app I am building requires some crucial info from server, before it can operate normally. Where would be the best place to retrieve this data and how to do it in such a way, that other components (MainActivity, any widgets from previous version) will resume after this data is available?

When user updates the app, he probably already has widgets on home screen and the data from server must be present for widgets to work (and he probably won't open the app since it was auto updated). Or, if it's a new user, he will most likely open up MainActivity first.

Because of this constraints, I am now checking for data both in MainActivity as well as in WidgetProvider.

Ideal solution would be to have a component which retrieves this data and then you could either tell it to get the data or, if data was already requested (but not available yet), subscribe to it and be notified when retrieval is done.

Is there any mechanism to achieve this?

Comment: I would use an EventBus for that  , check  for the data   in any component  (MainActivity would be my choice), and emit an event accordingly .

Comment: Sounds like you're looking for a Service or BroadcastReceiver. Otherwise, the Application class starts before the Activity classes

Comment: Maybe https://developer.android.com/training/sync-adapters/ will help

Answer (score 0):

You can extend Application class and then override onCreate() method;

Comment: This would work if the app wouldn't have any widgets - but in this case, WidgetProviders can run by themselves without Application class.

Comment: Yes, I see the struggle now. As mentioned above, seems like your only option is service started after boot. HOWEVER, there is no any guarantee that response from server will come before onUpdate() is called. So, I will do it in that way: when onUpdate() is called and data is not available, instead of widget content I will show some wait message or animation. As soon as service recieve the data, it will invoke widget update (which is pain in the ass itself).